# Terraform - Create variable that contains both object_id and display_name for a list of groups

Tags: loops, for-loop, terraform, azure-active-directory

I am struggling with generating a variable for ad_groups that contains both `object_id` and `display_name`.

My code looks like this:

```
module "my_users" {
   source                 = "../../my-module"
   ad_users_upns          = ["john.smith@domain.com", "jill.roberts@domain.com"]
   ad_groups_displaynames = ["ad-group-1","ad-group-2", "ad-group-44"]
}
```

my-module contains a data lookup for AD users (`data "azuread_users"`)
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/data-sources/users

```
data "azuread_users" "ad_approvers" {
  user_principal_names = var.ad_users_upns
}
```

This returns a `users` list that contains both the `object_id` **and** `display_name` for the user:

e.g.

```
    {
        display_name                   = "John Smith"
        object_id                      = "9de43ab0-0586-412a-98ce-c81cf9247e7c"
    },
    {
        display_name                   = "Jill Roberts"
        object_id                      = "9f49c29d-3a68-42b5-aea4-182895571ee7"
    },
```

I can then loop through this list to use both these properties in a dynamic variable:

```
dynamic "ad_approvers" {
  for_each = data.azuread_users.ad_appovers.users
    content {
      id = ad_approvers.value["object_id"]
      description = ad_approvers.value["display_name"]
    }
  }
```

---

I would like to achieve the same for the AD groups however `data "azuread_groups"` only returns `object_ids` **or** `display_names` as a single list.
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/data-sources/groups

If I define a local variable, I can't see how to pull the `object_id` through if I use `display_name`, or vice-versa:

```
# This only returns a list of display_names or object_ids  
data "azuread_groups" "allowed_groups" {
  display_names = var.ad_groups_displaynames 
  security_enabled = true
}

# Can't seem to get this local variable working to define the same properties
locals {
  adgroups = {
    for group in data.azuread_groups.allowed_groups.display_names : group => {
      object_id    = group.object_id  <-- how do I pull this through for each group?
      display_name = group
    }
  }
}
```

I want to end up with a variable that contains both `display_name` and `object_id` that represents the AD groups which I intend to also use in a dynamic variable similar to the ad_user dynamic variable above.

e.g.

```
dynamic "allowed_adgroups" {
  for_each = local.ad_groups
    content {
      id = allowed_adgroups.value["object_id"]
      description = allowed_adgroups.value["display_name"]
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: You haven't explained what value `data.azuread_groups.allowed_groups.display_names` has, nor what exactly do you expect your `local.adgroups` to be.

Comment: Apologies, I thought I had.

`data.azuread_groups.allowed_groups.display_names` is a list of strings (display_names).

I expect my `local.adgroups` to be a map which contains 2 properties - `display_name` and `object_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to achieve the same for the AD groups however  `data "azuread_groups"`  only returns  `object_ids`  **or**  `display_names`as a single list.

To display the `object_id` and `display_names` of **Azure AD** groups in a single list using variables, here is the updated `Terraform` code.

**Main.tf**

```json
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azuread = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azuread"
      version = "~> 2.15.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azuread" {
  tenant_id = "45678888d343-4afe-8230-e735719fv546bnh6"
}

data "azuread_users" "ad_users" {
  user_principal_names = var.ad_users_upns
}

data "azuread_groups" "ad_groups" {
  display_names    = var.ad_groups_displaynames
  security_enabled = true
}
locals {
  adgroup_map = {
    for idx, display_name in data.azuread_groups.ad_groups.display_names :
    display_name => data.azuread_groups.ad_groups.object_ids[idx]
  }

  combined_adgroups = [
    for display_name, object_id in local.adgroup_map :
    {
      display_name = display_name
      object_id    = object_id
    }
  ]
}

output "formatted_adgroups" {
  value = [
    for group in local.combined_adgroups :
    {
      display_name = group.display_name
      object_id    = group.object_id
    }
  ]
}
```

**Varaibles.tf**

```
 variable "ad_users_upns" {
  type    = list(string)
  description = "List of user principal names (UPNs) for Azure AD users"
  default = ["abc@xxx.onmicrosoft.com", "vnfnf@fffff9.onmicrosoft.com"]
}

variable "ad_groups_displaynames" {
  type    = list(string)
  description = "List of display names for Azure AD groups"
  default = ["DemoGroup", "demogroup1"]
}
```

After running the `Terraform` code I provided, the `Azure AD` Group **display names** and **Object IDs** are both displayed in a single list, as shown below.

[image]

**Terraform Apply:**

[image]